Postgresql table design: Should I use separate table and join them or pack them into array of JSON in one column
This is what my table looks like

which is the best approach to design this database?
And I use postgresql in Hasura(Graphql engine that generate graphql server by define database with no code)to create query and mutation.
I try to pack session data(many rows of data like a point survey follow by point name that save in template) into array of JSON in in Observation_data column.
I only need to know which is the best approach to design this database.
I want to implement them to create graphql api for robot ui which use to query and mutation the inspection data of thickness of iron pipe.
If you have another method that better than that two choice you can suggest me.
I concern about ACID rule of RDBMS.

A relational database tends to not be a good storage mechanism for image files.  The filesystem or a networked object store could be a better choice.  If the question is about SQL table design, are the other technologies you mention like GraphQL important?  Can you [edit] the question to include details about what you have so far (like an SQL CREATE TABLE statement) and the problems you're running into, making sure to include code details in plain text?

I mean Column Observation_data should I separate that column to new table or use embedded in one column as show as my picture? No image file store in table.

Can you explain what you intend to gain by putting it in an array? That is not how relational data is typically arranged and hasura will not operate as intended that way. Is there some specific issue you are trying to avoid?

Start with a 3NF data model, which is natural for a relational database like PostgreSQL. That worked for the last 50 years and will most likely work for the next 50 years.

@AbrahamLabkovsky It is my first time use RDBMS in my real project. Normally I use MongoDB and use embleded array method when I need to relational data because it's easy way, But I try to do the same in PostgreSQL in Schema page in Hasura and I can't do it, It always say wrong systax when I try to insert data to  JSONB[] or JSON[] column.

I have my full Schema picture But I'm afraid to show in public.

That is not the correct way to model your data in a RDB. You make a separate table and use foreign keys.  You might want to watch a video or read an article or 2 on the subject. Essentially, Mongo follows a different paradigm and you should not do that in any RDB and certainly not if you want to use hasura
